# why does x have junk value?

Tags: c

i need to print a sequence of numbers starting with N, without using loop, in which  A[i+1] = A[i] - 5,  if  A[i]>0, else A[i+1]=A[i] + 5  repeat it until A[i]=N.

example:
input

> 1
>
> 10

output:
10 5 0 5 10

i have written 2 recursive functions and called them from a series function. but the second half isnt working because of some junk value present in x.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rec2(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    if(n == n1) return;
    else
    {
        rec2(n + 5, n1);
    }
    
}


int rec(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);
    
    if(n > 0)
    {
        rec(n - 5, n1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("returning :%d \n", n);
        return n;
    }
    
}

void series(int n, int n1)
{
    int x;
    x = rec(n, n1);
    printf("llllll\n%d ", x);
    return;

    // rec2(x, n1);
}

int main() {
    //code
    int t;
    scanf("%d ", &t);
    
    while(t--){
        
        int n, n1;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        // printf("%d ", n);
        n1 = n;
        /*if(n > 0)
        {
            n = n - 5;  
        }
        else
        {
            n = n + 5;
        }
        printf("%d ", n); */
        
        series(n, n1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your compiler doesn't emit warning about your program then enable more warnings and treat them as errors. The compiler is good at detecting problems, like some function not returning values for all paths.

Comment: while(t--) is it really works? I think you should get endless loop.

Comment: @FerruxNebiyev That's not a problem. It will loop if `t` has a non-zero value, then `t` is decremented after the test.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your recursive function rec.

```
int rec(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);

    if(n > 0)
    {
        rec(n - 5, n1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("returning :%d \n", n);
        return n;
    }
}
```

If we take a closer look at how it works we can see the problem:

1st it is called with rec(10,10)
That mean it is executed this part of the code:

```
int rec(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);

    if(n > 0)
    {
        rec(n - 5, n1);
```

Then the function is called again with rec (5,10) and it's executed again until here:

```
int rec(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);

    if(n > 0)
    {
        rec(n - 5, n1);
```

Then the function is called again with rec (0.10) and it's executed again, this time it goes trough else and it prints and returns the value of n.

```
    printf("returning :%d \n", n);
    return n;
}
```

Because it is a recursive function it's job isn't done yet because there are some values that were stored in the stack and it goes back to them.
The stack looks like that:

| 0 |

| 5 |

| 10|

Since the job is done with the value 0 it goes back where it remains with the value of 5. And here is the problem. The code returns at this line:

```
int rec(int n, int n1)
{
    printf("%d ", n);

    if(n > 0)
    {
        rec(n - 5, n1); <---- here
    }
```

And it continue his execution. Since it is nothing to execute and nothing to return it return some garbage value and goes again with the value 10 left on the stack and does again the same process.
That's why you got some garbage value of x. Because x got the last value returned by the function witch is the value return after the last value was taken from the stack.

This is not the solution of what are you trying to do, it's the explanation why are you getting garbage value in x.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

this will work if `n>0`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rec(int n, int l, int nw)
{
    if(n >= 0) {
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
    if(!nw && n==l) {
        return 0;
    }
    if( nw && n > 0) {
        return rec(n - 5, l, nw);
    }
    nw = 0;
    return rec(n + 5, l, nw);
}

int main() {
    int n,t;

    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d", &n);
        rec(n,n, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```